# supplement numpy array in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

How do I supplemented by a `numpy` array of zeros?

```
arr = np.array([1,10])

if len(arr) < size:
  # supplemented array of zeros to the size
```

For example `size = 5`;

```
if array = [1,2,3].
output array = [1,2,3,0,0]
```

Should I call `fill` or make a new array like `arr + [0]*(size-len)`?

Which is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`ndarray.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.resize((5,))
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

Comment: or use numpy.pad... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: @JulienBernu -- Yeah, I just looked for a `np.resize` -- It turns out that there is `np.resize` and also `ndarray.resize`.  The former repeats the array which isn't what OP wants, but the latter pads with `0` as OP wants, so I don't see any good reason not to use it... :-)